# Configuring vim hanging indents

Tags: vim

How can I configure in my vimrc how many leading tabs to insert in "hanging indents," example below.

```
void myfn(int x,
        int y, // 8 spaces here = 2 tabs
        int z);
```

I am interested in configuring the number of tabs that are auto inserted in the line with "int y". E.g., how can I change from 2 tabs (which seems to be what my vimrc is doing today) to 1 tab?

Comment: Could you please post your `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re coding C, you’re looking for `:help cinoptions-values`.

More specifically, check out `cino-(` and `cino-w`.